# Database.EnsureCreated() force create multiple schemas

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, npgsql

We are using .NET Core 3.1, [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v3.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.9) and [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL v3.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/3.1.4). We have 2 database schemas and corresponding `DbContext` files:

| **schema** | **DbContext** |
| --- | --- |
| `test1` | `Test1DbContext.cs` |
| `test2` | `Test2DbContext.cs` |

`Test1DbContext.cs`:

```cs
public partial class Test1DbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<AppModules> AppModules { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AppOffice> AppOffice { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AppRoles> AppRoles { get; set; }
}
```

`Test2DbContext.cs`:

```cs
public partial class Test2DbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<CacuInter> CacuInter { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Caseevents> Caseevents { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Caseftpses> Caseftpses { get; set; }
}
```

Database models are defined like this:

```cs
[Table("app_modules", Schema = "test1")]
public partial class AppModules
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [Column("name")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When we start integration tests, we want to delete the database and recreate both schemas (`test1` and `test2`). This is the code snippet that we have currently:

```cs
private void PrepareDatabase(Test1DbContext test1DbContext, Test2DbContext test2DbContext)
{
    // this drops the *whole* database, not just the `test1` schema
    test1DbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    
    // create `test1` schema
    test1DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
    
    // nothing happens here because EF Core thinks that the database has already been created
    test2DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

We start with `test1DbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted()` which drops the whole database. Then, we create schema `test1` with `test1DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()`. At the end, we also want to create schema `test2` with `test2DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()`, but nothing happens because EF Core thinks that the database has already been created.

How can I force EF Core to create **both** schemas?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29144